# How do I obtain File Version info from a C++ exe in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, assemblies, version, fileinfo

I need to get the File version information from an exe file originally written in C++ from a C# program.

Using Assembly.LoadFile(fullpath).GetName().Version results in a BadImageFormatException.

Can anyone help?

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `using System.Diagnostics`, and then:

```
    FileVersionInfo info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path);
```

Then look at the various properties of `info`:

```
    Console.WriteLine(info.CompanyName);
    Console.WriteLine(info.ProductName);
    Console.WriteLine(info.LegalCopyright);
    Console.WriteLine(info.ProductVersion);
```

etc